# How to join two queries in SQL from 3 tables?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables (M:N) - Tests, Tests_Questions, Questions.

**Tests**

```
ID
Name
```

**Test_Questions**

```
IDTests
IDQuestions
```

**Questions**

```
ID
Text
```

What I need is select all from tests and count of question related to this test.

Can you please help me with this query? I am not able to solve it.

Comment: Select * from tests, test_questions where tests.id = test_questions.idtests

Comment: Thank you for help, Dotnetom gave me right anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join and grouping:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, COUNT(tq.IDQuestions) as numberOfQuestions
FROM Tests t INNER JOIN Test_Questions tq ON t.ID = tq.IDTests
GROUP BY t.ID, t.Name
```

Since you only need counts it is enough to join just `Tests` and `Test_Questions` tables, you don't need `Questions`